# Proper way to perform AJAX call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am currently performing AJAX in "oldschool php way":

`/home/index.html`

```
  <%= button_to 'Get message', :id => 'get_message' %>
  <div id="message"></div>
```

`assets/javascript/index.coffee`

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#get_message').on(
    'click',
    ->
      $.post(
        '/home/message/',
        (data) ->
          $('#message').text(data.message)
      )
  )
```

`app/controllers/home`

```
def message
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :message => 'Hello, world!' } }
  end
end
```

Is the way I do it a good practice or is there any better way? Thanks!

Comment: Look up the `link_to_remote` functionality and it's replacements in rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

To stuff like that, you could use `:remote` option in [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) and [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) tags.